# System.Reactive Throttling an async method

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have been putting off using reactive extensions for so long, and I thought this would be a good use. Quite simply, I have a method that can be called for various reasons on various code paths

```
private async Task GetProductAsync(string blah) {...}
```

I need to be able to *throttle* this method. That's to say, I want to stop the flow of calls until no more calls are made (for a specified period of time). Or more clearly, if 10 calls to this method happen within a certain time period, i want to limit (throttle) it to only 1 call (after a period) when the last call was made.

I can see an example using a method with `IEnumerable`, this kind of makes sense

```
static IEnumerable<int> GenerateAlternatingFastAndSlowEvents() 
{ ... }

...

var observable = GenerateAlternatingFastAndSlowEvents().ToObservable().Timestamp();
var throttled = observable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(750));

using (throttled.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", x.Value, x.Timestamp)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to unsubscribe");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
Console.ReadKey();
```

However, (and this has always been my major issue with Rx, forever), how do I create an `Observable` from a simple `async` method.

**Update**

I have managed to find an alternative approach using *ReactiveProperty*

```
Barcode = new ReactiveProperty<string>();
Barcode.Select(text => Observable.FromAsync(async () => await GetProductAsync(text)))
       .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
       .Switch()
       .ToReactiveProperty();
```

The premise is I catch it at the text property `Barcode`, however it has its own drawbacks, as `ReactiveProperty` takes care of notification, and I cant silently update the backing field as its already managed.

To summarise, how can I convert an `async` method call to Observable, so I can user the Throttle method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two key ways of converting a Task to an Observable, with an important difference between them.

```
Observable.FromAsync(()=>GetProductAsync("test"));
```

and

```
GetProductAsync("test").ToObservable();
```

The first will not start the Task until you subscribe to it.
The second will create (and start) the task and the result will either immediately or sometime later appear in the observable, depending on how fast the Task is.

Looking at your question in general though, it seems that you want to stop *the flow of calls.* You do not want to throttle the flow of results, which would result in unnecessary computation and loss.

If this is your aim, your GetProductAsync could be seen as an *observer* of call events, and the GetProductAsync should throttle those calls. One way of achieving that would be to declare a

```
public event Action<string> GetProduct;
```

and use

```
  var callStream= Observable.FromEvent<string>( 
             handler =>  GetProduct+= handler , 
             handler => GetProduct-= handler);
```

The problem then becomes how to return the result and what should happen when your 'caller's' call is throttled out and discarded.

One approach there could be to declare a type "GetProductCall" which would have the input string and output result as properties.

You could then have a setup like:

```
var callStream= Observable.FromEvent<GetProductCall>( 
             handler =>  GetProduct+= handler , 
             handler => GetProduct-= handler)
            .Throttle(...)
            .Select(r=>async r.Result= await GetProductCall(r.Input).ToObservable().FirstAsync());
```

(code not tested, just illustrative)

Another approach might include the Merge(N) overload that limits the max number of concurrent observables.

Answer (score 2):

Unrelated to your question, but probably helpful: Rx's `Throttle` operator is really a debounce operator. The closest thing to a throttling operator is `Sample`. Here's the difference (assuming you want to throttle or debounce to one item / 3 seconds):

```
items   : --1-23----4-56-7----8----9-
throttle: --1--3-----4--6--7--8-----9
debounce: --1-------4--6------8----9-
```

`Sample`/throttle will bunch items that arrive in the sensitive time and emit the last one on the next sampling tick. Debounce throws away items that arrive in the sensitive time, then re-starts the clock: The only way for an item to emit is if it was preceded by Time-Range of silence.

RX.Net's `Throttle` operator does what `debounce` above depicts. `Sample` does what `throttle` above depicts.

If you want something different, describe how you want to throttle.

Comment: I used throttle as it was the terminology of the library in question. However it is probably debounce

Comment: Certainly agree. In the `System.Reactive.Linq.Observable` (Version=5.0.0) the XML doc of the `Throttle()` method confirms this fact: *"... For streams that never have gaps larger than or equal to dueTime between elements, the resulting stream won't produce
any elements. In order to reduce the volume of a stream whilst guaranteeing the
periodic production of elements, consider using the `Observable.Sample` set of
operators."*